# Difference about heightForRowAt and set rowHeight in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two tableview in the same view controller, `tableview1` and `tableview2`, the cells height in both tableviews are fixed, and I also set `delegate` and `dataSource` for them, the only difference is that `tableview1` already have data when I enter the view controller, but `tableview2` don't.

My question is I can set tableview1's row height by `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat` but for `tableview2` I have to set `self.tableview2.rowHeight` in `viewDidLoad()`, why is that?

**EDIT**

**Code**

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView1: UITableView! // tag = 1
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView2: UITableView! // tag = 2

    var getDataViewController: GetDataViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.tableView1.delegate = self
        self.tableView1.dataSource = self
        self.tableView2.delegate = self
        self.tableView2.dataSource = self

        self.tableView2.rowHeight = 44 // work for tableView2

        getDataViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "getData") as! GetDataViewController
    }

    // ...


    // Table View DataSource
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView.tag == 1 {
            return tableView1DataArray.count
        }
        else if tableView.tag == 2 {
            return tableView2DataArray.count
        }
    }

    // Table View Delegate
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if tableView.tag == 1 {
            return 122 // work for tableView1
        }
        return 44 // not work for tableView2
    }
}
```

I get tableView2's data in other view controller:

```
class GetDataViewController: UIViewController {
    var mainViewController: MainViewController!        
    // ...
    @IBAction func ok(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let index = IndexPath(row: tableView2.count, section: 0)
        // ...
        let data = SomeData()
        tableView2DataArray.append(data)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            mainViewController.tableView2.inserRows(at: [index], with: .automatic)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the `rowHeight` property and the delegate method `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)` is that the delegate method is called for every cell and usually contains basic calculations (it might be expensive when you've a lot of rows). 
In your case, since the row height is fixed and the same for every cell, it's better to use the `rowHeight` property for both the `UITableView` instances.

The delegate method is called whenever you reload the tableView/section (using `reloadData()` or any other reload method), so please make sure you're calling it once you got the data.

> You may set the row height for cells if the delegate doesn’t implement the tableView(_:heightForRowAt:) method. The default value of rowHeight is UITableViewAutomaticDimension
>
> [...]
>
> There are performance implications to using tableView(*:heightForRowAt:) instead of rowHeight. Every time a table view is displayed, it calls tableView(*:heightForRowAt:) on the delegate for each of its rows
>
> [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614852-rowheight)

Comment: So if I don't have data yet, `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)` is useless? Also,   when I got data and using `reloadData()`, `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)` still not working, why?

Comment: The delegate method is called whenever there is a cell to be shown. You might have returned a `0` number of rows per section (check that method) and check if it is actually called by using breakpoints.

Comment: I am sure number of rows per section is not `0`, but rowHeight will set to be `-1.0` if I use `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)`

Comment: Can you please update your first post by inserting your code? @ioio007

Comment: @ioio007 can you please update it with the part where you set the `rowHeight` property and the `numberOfRowsInSection`? Thanks